# Function to run when drop down is clicked

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, lookup-column

I have a `lookup field`. I need to filter the values in that drop-down, so I thought of writing function when the drop down control is clicked.

Something like.

```
$("select[title='Subsystem']").click(alert(""));
```

But this doesn't work.
 How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Change` event

```
$("select[title='Subsystem']").change(function () { alert($(this).val()); });
```

**Update**: Click event

```
$("select[title='Subsystem']").click(function(v){ console.log(v.target.value); });
```

Comment: this works when item is selected from the drop down but I need when the drop down is clicked, i mean when the drop down is opened....

Comment: You want to re-arrange the options inside that drop down? Once you click the drop?

Comment: What you wanna do when dropdown is opened ?? either you will select something or will move out.

what is your actual requirement ?